# How to add click events for the items in the drawer bar

Tags: java, android, xml, navigation-drawer

So basically I have an app in the making that uses navigation drawer to navigate across all activity. I have successfully make the drawer but the items inside were unable to respond and bring me to the respective activity.

This is part of my MainActivity.java that should do the action:

```
NavigationView nv = (NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.nv1);

        nv.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                    case(R.id.btLogout):
                        logout();
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Logging Out", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),LoginActivity.class);
                        startActivity(in);
                        break;
                    case(R.id.enquiries):
                        Intent in2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), EnquiryActivity.class);
                        startActivity(in2);
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

private void logout()
    {
        session.setLoggedIn(false);
        finish();
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
    }
```

And this is my navigation_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:id="@+id/timetable"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_schedule_black_24dp"
        android:title="Timetable"></item>

    <item android:id="@+id/attendance"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_trending_up_black_24dp"
        android:title="Attendance"></item>

    <item android:id="@+id/weeklyreport"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_assignment_black_24dp"
        android:title="Weekly Report"></item>

    <item android:id="@+id/upcomingevents"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_event_black_24dp"
        android:title="Upcoming Events"></item>

    <item android:id="@+id/announcements"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_announcement_black_24dp"
        android:title="Announcements"></item>

    <item android:id="@+id/enquiries"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_person_black_24dp"
        android:title="Enquiries"></item>

    <item android:id="@+id/btLogout"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_highlight_off_black_24dp"
        android:title="Logout"></item>

</menu>
```

May I know where did I go wrong? I'm quite new to this but I tried my best. Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the method below:

```
    NavigationView nv = (NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.nv1);

       nv.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                    switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                        case(R.id.btLogout):
                            logout();
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Logging Out", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
                            break;
                        case(R.id.enquiries):
startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, EnquiryActivity.class));
                            break;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }
```